# Create an Anonymous Function with no Parameter in Scala

Tags: scala, function, reflection, anonymous-function

We know that in Scala reflection, we can invoke a method using

```
clazz.getDeclaredMethod("method").invoke(instance, parameters)
```

where the function signature of `invoke` is `Object invoke(Object obj, Object... args)`.

If we want to make an anonymous function for the above with one parameter, we can write as

```
val method: Function1[Object, Object] = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("method").invoke(instance, _)
```

My question is, how to make an anonymous function with NO parameter?

Simply writing `clazz.getDeclaredMethod("method").invoke(instance)` will call the method without any argument, instead of making it as an anonymous function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `_` syntax is sugar in the first place and is the same as:

```
val method: Function1[Object, Object] = x => clazz.getDeclaredMethod("method").invoke(instance, x)
```

In order to write a similar function with no parameter:

```
val method: Function0[Object] = () => clazz.getDeclaredMethod("method").invoke(instance)
```